# Loop returns Partial results in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, loops, sqlite

Only a Python beginner here and I've already spent a few hours looking at this trying to figure out what I did wrong...

I am using a sqlString to pick any 10 stores from one dataset and querying the storeID. The next step I'm taking is to loop the results of my sqlString to query another table and give me 25 random results for each of the 10 store IDs in my first query.

The problem I'm having is that my output only seems to return the 25 matches for one random store. So even though I should get 250 total records (25 * 10), I only get 25 records in my output. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Here is the code I am using:

```
sqlstring = """
select StoreID from tblStoreData where State = 'NY' order by random() limit 10"""

NYstores = myCursor.execute(sqlstring).fetchall()
print NYstores

for storeID in NYstores:
    sqlstring = """select * from tblDistance where FromStore = %s order by random() limit 25""" % (storeID)
    otherStore = myCursor.execute(sqlstring).fetchall()

print otherStore
myConnection = sqlite3.connect('RestaurantData.db')
myCursor = myConnection.cursor()
```

-Nick

Comment: Please correct your indentation first.

Comment: The code posted here cannot work at all, throwing a fatal error on the first `myCursor.execute` line. Please edit your question to contain what you are actually running.

Comment: Please post whatever output your program is spitting out.

Answer (score 0):

Python is indentation-sensitive. Indent the lines following the 'for' loop line in order to get full looping.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where the for loop ends (becasuse there's no identation), but could it be that you are looping through NYstores assigning the fetch to the same variable overriding the previous value?

I think you should try append (rather than assign) the new values in the for loop before printing it out.

Something like this may work:

```
result = []
for storeID in NYstores:
    sqlstring = """select * from tblDistance where FromStore = %s order by random() limit 25""" % (storeID)
    otherStore = myCursor.execute(sqlstring).fetchall()
    for item in otherStore:
        result.append(item)

print result
```

I'm sure there would be something prettier, but it's what I came up to right now.